# Flask app running in AWS beanstalk not able to connect to remote cassandra

Tags: flask, cassandra, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, datastax

I am running a `python(3.4)` flask app on aws beanstalk. When I login to ec2 shell and try to run flask app locally, it runs properly and easily fetches data from remote `cassandra`. But while fetching data from `cassandra`, the app run by AWS eb keep throwing following errors in httpd/error_log.

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /user/1003 [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 53, in user_profile
data = get_user_data(id)
File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 163, in get_user_data
if obj:
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py", line 393, in __le
n__
self._execute_query()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py", line 428, in _exe
cute_query
self._result_generator = (i for i in self._execute(self._select_query()))
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py", line 360, in _exe
cute
result = _execute_statement(self.model, statement, self._consistency, self._timeout)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/query.py", line 1412, in _ex
ecute_statement
parts = model._routing_key_from_values(key_values, connection.get_cluster().protocol_version)
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/connection.py", line 183, in
 get_cluster
raise CQLEngineException("%s.cluster is not configured. Call one of the setup or default functions firs
t." % __name__)
cassandra.cqlengine.CQLEngineException: cassandra.cqlengine.connection.cluster is not configured. Call one
of the setup or default functions first.
```

My env:

```
(venv)[ec2-user@ip-11.1.1.1 ~]$ pip freeze
cassandra-driver==3.6.0
click==6.6
Cython==0.24.1
Flask==0.11
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
six==1.10.0
Werkzeug==0.11.11
xmltodict==0.10.2
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't setup the connection to Cassandra first. You need to do this before you can execute queries against it.

Comment: Actually I do this in my application's main function if __name__ == "__main__":
    connection.setup([config.CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_IP], config.CONST_KEYSPACE, protocol_version=3)
    os.environ["CQLENG_ALLOW_SCHEMA_MANAGEMENT"] = "Yes"
    sync_table(mytable)

Comment: Is the env var set?

Comment: My Bad. I was setting the connection with in __main__ function.  AWS configuration for Elastic Beanstalk configures the WSGI environment (it’s Apache + WSGI in the backend). When it was being run in the EB environment, the main function was getting called. I moved the connection code outside main function and it started working.